# Bulk upsert with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, upsert

[bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) with `ignore_conflicts=True` insert new records only and doesn't update existing one. 
[bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) updates only existing records and doesn't insert new one.

Now I see only one variant to make upsert is a raw query:

```py
from catalog.models import Product

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.executemany(
        """
        INSERT INTO app_table (pk, col1, col2) 
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            col1 = VALUES(col1), 
            col2 = VALUES(col2); 
        """,
        [
            ('1', 'val1', 'val2'),
            ('2', 'val1', 'val2'),
        ]
    )
```

Is there another way to perform bulk upsert in Django?

Comment: Surely you run bulk_create followed by bulk_update?

Comment: @FiddleStix Anyway bulk performs more than one query if amount of data more then `bulk_size`, so it's a good decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a traditional method to use create and update in a single query in MySQL. I 
 see that you've used `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` which is a common approach in these cases. An alternative lengthy approach:

- Update a portion of your data in a temporary table, essentially COPY to your temp table -> `cursor.copy_from()`, then UPDATE to your original table.

Also, you could optimize performance by increasing your cache size, and setting `DEBUG=False` if you don't need metadeta in your logs [Ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/).

Perhaps also test the same data using PostgreSQL, and check if it results in better performance.

Answer (score 3):

As of Django 4.1, the **[`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create)** method supports *upserts* via **`update_conflicts`**:

```
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(
    queryset, 
    update_conflicts=True, 
    update_fields=['col1', 'col2'],
    unique_fields=['col3'],
)
```